# Where to get free high quality maps (vector)

Tags: vector, maps

So I search for a long time, but couldn't find anything...

So basically I'm searching for high quality maps to create something similar like:

- https://www.mapiful.com
- https://www.mujumaps.com

The map is based on Openstreetmaps, but I don't know where to get high quality images or vector data to create a similar map

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can download the OpenStreetMap (OSM) data as svg files. Alternatively you can also download the raw data and generate a vector image if you need more control.

There are many ways to do this, of different complexities and some of them are quite convoluted. However the simplest is to just click on the share icon in OSM web interface and download a section as PDF or SVG. Note that the SVG that OSM produces by default is optimized for inkscape and does not work well in illustrator for example but the postscript is OK, although its not very well organized for editing. But ist possible to regenerate the map in a more illustrator friendly SVG, read the docs.

Comment: I will look into this, but maybe I will just develop something in my freetime that sovles the problem. I just thought of something like this: Setup a server with allready styled tiles, than render the tiles you need/selected and merge multiple 2000x2000 png tiles into a big one which would be enough for 300dpi printing. Maybe even 600dpi. But currently I have no time to start a project like this.